# React generating UI from object - console.log works but nothing generated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have code that generates my react UI, and it works with a list of languages to generate checkboxes for language selection. For example when in state

```
languages = {English: true, French: false}
```

however when i change it to an object which contains the values from the DB, I get no error, but nothing loads.

```
[
{
    "language_name": "English",
    "lang_num": 1,
    "checked": false
},
{
    "language_name": "Mandarin Chinese",
    "lang_num": 2,
    "checked": false
},
]
```

The code is:

```
       {   
        Object.entries(this.props.languages).forEach(([key, value]) => {
          console.log(this.props.languages[key].language_name),
          <label id="checkbox-margin">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value={this.props.languages[key].language_name}  
              checked={this.props.languages[key].checked}
              onChange={this.handleLangClick}
            /> {this.props.languages[key].language_name}
          </label>
      }
      )
```

The console.log lists each language string fine, i get them all printed in the console, but nothing is generated on the UI. Any idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `map` function to iterate through the array:

```
{this.props.languages ? this.props.languages.map(language => {
    return (
        <label id="checkbox-margin" key={language.lang_num}>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                value={language.language_name}  
                checked={language.checked}
                onChange={this.handleLangClick}
            /> {language.language_name}
        </label>
    )}) : 'Loading languages...'
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, out of interested why doesnt .entries work here?

Comment: @dooglex Your JSON response is an array of objects and not a simple object like your example state